# Loading full PDF file in memory for faster lookups

Tags: pdf, search, memory, ram

Is there a quick&dirty way of loading a full pdf file in memory in linux? I have a large pdf file (about 1gb) that's a result of merging several other pdfs together, with different structures. The resulting pdf has already been optimized (I only need text searches). Lookups take several seconds, and I was wondering if there was a way to load the full file in memory permanently to decrease search times.

Comment: You can use a pdf library to do that manually, but a 1 GiB file is huge, especially since AFAIK PDF files are compressed using deflate so the uncompressed version in RAM will take significantly more space. Besides, PDF files tends to contain vector informations. Manipulating this tends to be slow. To make things faster, engines tend to use more RAM (there is often a balance between the RAM usage and speed). If you have a lot of RAM, then it can be a good idea, otherwise probably not. It might be a good solution regarding the exact operation done to split the PDF in many independent parts.